# Смена пользователя вместе с директорией (Добавление нового пользователя в Linux)

Tags: linux, shell

Понадобилось создать пользователя вместе с его домашней директорией, это я делаю с помощью скрипта, а если кратко описывая то:

```
useradd ivan && passwd ivan && mkdir /home/ivan
```

Я вижу что этот пользователь создался в файле `/etc/passwd` и его домашняя директория готова, но когда я меняю пользователя `su ivan` вписываю его пароль, я оказываюсь в той же директории из которой поменял данного пользователя. А хотелось бы оказаться в `/home/ivan`. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо

Comment: `useradd -h` поможет разобраться с проблемой.  В частности `-m` создать домашний каталог пользователя. Но если вы уже создали пользователя, то теперь нужно воспользоваться `usermod` с ключем `-d` также подробно разобраться в параметрах можно `usermod -h`

Comment: @PotroNik, спасибо)

Comment: `su` да оставляет текущий каталог, но домашний меняет, если сделаете `cd` или `cd ~` по попадёте куда надо

Comment: @PavelGridin кстати да, хорошее замечание, что бы переходить в домашний каталог нужно писать `su - ivan`

Comment: @PotroNik, `-` — это не только про домашний каталог (как раз переход в домашний каталог — одно из следствий такой команды).  _-, -l, --login
              Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:_